# Cakephp: Adding new attachment without adding a new project

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

I'm using the Upload Plugin 2.0 josegonzalez.
An image uploader for Cakephp thats works fantastic.

But i got a problem, i am able to use the `createWithAttachments` part of the Plugin. 
Everything works well, except for one thing. I dont want to create a new Project (id, name etc) when im uploading new attachments (photo's).

A project has more attachements (photo's) it is possible for a user to upload a total of 10 photo's for each project.

code from the `Project.php` **(the model)**

```
<?php
    class Project extends AppModel {
      /* the rest of your model here */

      public function createWithAttachments($data) {
        // Sanitize your images before adding them
        $images = array();
        if (!empty($data['Image'][0])) {
          foreach ($data['Image'] as $i => $image) {
            if (is_array($data['Image'][$i])) {
              // Force setting the `model` field to this model
              $image['model'] = 'Project';

              $images[] = $image;
            }
          }
        }
        $data['Image'] = $images;

        // Try to save the data using Model::saveAll()
        $this->create();
        if ($this->saveAll($data)) {
          return true;
        }

        // Throw an exception for the controller
        throw new Exception(__("This post could not be saved. Please try again"));
      }
    } 
?>
```

Code from `ProjectsController.php` **(the controller)**

```
<?php
    class ProjectsController extends AppController {
      /* the rest of your controller here */
      public function cms_album() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          try {
            $this->Project->createWithAttachments($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The message has been saved'));
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->Session->setFlash($e->getMessage());
          }
        }
      }
    } 
?>
```

Each time i add 10 photo's to the database table `attachments` it created a new project in the database table `projects`. I just want the attachments to be new and save the id from the project that i get from the form part `echo $this->Form->input('Image.'.$i.'.foreign_key', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => ''.$this->params->pass[0].''));`

I hope i wrote my problem clearly and that somebody can help me. I tried a lot of things, even trying to accomplish with an `AttachmentsController` *(with no luck)*

**UPDATE:** (After the awnser of **Anil kumar** )

This is a `print_r` on `$data` before it uses `if($this->saveAll($data))`

```
Array
(
    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN4923.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGbIKTl
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 141994
                        )    
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN4921.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJBeYxk
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 216931
                        )    
                )    
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN3810.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpR6sflk
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 1304426
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `$this->create();` in your project model,

and ensure that `$data` doesn't contain any data related to the project `$this->saveAll($data);`

```
The "saveAll" function is just a wrapper around the "saveMany" and "saveAssociated" methods.
```

so it'll save the model data as well as associated models data, 
it's better to use `$this->Image->saveMany($data)` instead of 
`$this->saveAll($data)`

For more information, please check [saveAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array).

**Update**

just comment these lines.

```
// $this->create();
// if ($this->saveAll($data)) {
//   return true;
// }
```

and replace the above with

```
if ($this->Image->saveMany($data)) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I removed `$this->create();` as you said.. but still it makes a new project with id, instead using the id that im giving.. i have the question updated with an `print_r` of `$data`

Comment: why don't you use `$this->Image->saveMany()` ? instead of `$this->saveAll($data)`

Comment: Im sorry for the late reaction, but im trying to use `saveMany()` but it doesn't work.. Could you give me an example hw to use it? The reason that i use `saveAll` is because in the documentation of the uploader it says that i need to use that and everything works.. instead of that part...

Comment: instead of `$this->create()` and `$this->saveAll($data)` you can use `$this->Image->saveMany($data)` in your code.

Comment: I dont know what im doing wrong, because it wont work.. it doesn't update the images in the database and it doens't give an error..

Comment: can you check by printing the results using `debug($this->Image->saveMany)`

Comment: It says `Null`, probably the reason why its still empty in my db

Comment: Just check for validationerrors by doing `$this->Image->validationErrors`. May be this is the reason it's not saving into the DB.

Comment: It gives me an empty array.. getting a headache not knowing what im doing wrong...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41474/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-c-travel)

Comment: I will give you at least the **50 reputation**, because of all the effort you put in. I really hope that we can come to the right and working anwser so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

To add new associated records you need to specify the id of the Project that you want to add content to:

```
<?php
    class Project extends AppModel {
      /* the rest of your model here */

      public function createWithAttachments($data) {
        $data['Image'] = $this->sanitizeImages($data);

        // Try to save the data using Model::saveAll()
        $this->create();
        if ($this->saveAll($data)) {
          return true;
        }

        // Throw an exception for the controller
        throw new Exception(__("This post could not be saved. Please try again"));
      }

      public function addAttachments($data) {
        $data['Image'] = $this->sanitizeImages($data);

        // Make sure you have and id on $this-id and Try to save the data
        if ($this->getID() && $this->Image->save($data)) {
          return true;
        }

        // Throw an exception for the controller
        throw new Exception(__("This post could not be saved. Please try again"));
      }

      private function sanitizeImages($data) {
        // Sanitize your images before adding them
        $images = array();
        if (!empty($data['Image'][0])) {
          foreach ($data['Image'] as $i => $image) {
            if (is_array($data['Image'][$i])) {
              // Force setting the `model` field to this model
              $image['model'] = 'Project';

              $images[] = $image;
            }
          }
        }

        return $images;
      }
    }
```

?>

And in your controller you can do

```
 $this->Project->id = $id;
 $this->Project->addAttachments($data);
```

I'm not 100% sure the code will work, it is just intended to give you an idea of what needs to be done.

Another solution to this would be to send the project id in the data.

```
Array
(
    [Project] => Array(
        [id] => 1 //Here goes the id of the project you would like to add attachments to
    ),
    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN4923.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGbIKTl
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 141994
                        )    
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN4921.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJBeYxk
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 216931
                        )    
                )    
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Project
                    [foreign_key] => 7
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => DSCN3810.JPG
                            [type] => image/jpeg
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpR6sflk
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 1304426
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Im already setting the right `id` in the `[foreign_key] => 7` ... it just that he overide it for some reason...